# Amortization example

Tags: java, decimalformat

This is my code:

```
  public class exampleaAmortizationProgram {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.printf("Loam amount");
     double loamAmount = input.nextDouble();

     System.out.print("Number of Years:");
     int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();

     System.out.print("Annual Interest Rate(8.25): ");
     double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

     double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;

     //compute mortgage 
     double monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment(loamAmount, numberOfYears, monthlyInterestRate);

     double balance = loamAmount;
     double interest;
     double principal;

     System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " + monthlyPayment * 100/ 100.0);
     System.out.println("Total Payment: " + monthlyPayment * 12 + numberOfYears * 100/ 100.0 + "\n");

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfYears * 12; i++) {
        interest = monthlyInterestRate * balance * 100 / 100.0;
        principal = monthlyPayment - interest * 100 / 100.0;
        balance = balance - principal * 100 / 100.0;

        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + df.format(interest) + "\t\t" + df.format(principal) + "\t\t" + df.format(balance));
    }       
    }
private static double monthlyPayment(double loamAmount, int numberOfYears, double monthlyInterestRate) {
    double monthlyPayment = loamAmount + monthlyInterestRate / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + monthlyInterestRate), numberOfYears * 12)));
    return monthlyPayment;
}
}
```

I have looked over different ways to do the DecimalFormat but its still saying that I have an error specifically in that code source:

```
exampleaAmortizationProgram.java:44: error: 
cannot find symbol DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Help please.

Comment: exampleaAmortizationProgram.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
  ^

Comment: in you sysout you have "-" instead of "+":         System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + df.format(interest) + "\t\t" !!!!!!-!!!!!! df.format(principal) + "\t\t" + df.format(balance));

Comment: please show the complete source code. How do these variables get initialised?

Comment: In System.out.print there is „-„. If you want to substract, you need to put this into anothee „()”.

Comment: public class exampleaAmortizationProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.printf("Loam amount");
   double loamAmount = input.nextDouble();
   
   System.out.print("Number of Years:");
   int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();
   
   System.out.print("Annual Interest Rate(8.25): ");
   double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();
   
   double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;

Comment: //compute mortgage 
   double monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment(loamAmount, numberOfYears, monthlyInterestRate);
   
   double balance = loamAmount;
   double interest;
   double principal;
   
   System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " + monthlyPayment * 100/ 100.0);
   System.out.println("Total Payment: " + monthlyPayment * 12 + numberOfYears * 100/ 100.0 + "\n");

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
  for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfYears * 12; i++) {
   interest = monthlyInterestRate * balance * 100 / 100.0;
   principal = monthlyPayment - interest * 100 / 100.0;
   balance = balance - principal * 100 / 100.0;
   
   System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + df.format(interest) + "\t\t" - df.format(principal) + "\t\t" + df.format(balance));
  }  
  }

Comment: private static double monthlyPayment(double loamAmount, int numberOfYears, double monthlyInterestRate) {
  double monthlyPayment = loamAmount + monthlyInterestRate / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + monthlyInterestRate), numberOfYears * 12)));
  return monthlyPayment;

Comment: @dianahernandez You can click the [edit] button to put more information.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + df.format(interest) + "\t\t" -
>   df.format(principal) + "\t\t" + df.format(balance));

You got „-„ there.